# How should I go about geolocating 1,100,000 lines of coordinate information?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, google-geocoder

Okay, so I'm trying to envision a solution for this. I have a database with over a million lines which includes a city name in the US and a set of coordinates for that city. The problem is that there are multiple cities with the same name: Springfield, NJ and Springfield, MA, for example. So I need to get the state information.

There are also duplicates within the data. There are only about 6500 sets of unique coordinates, so conceivably, I could locate those and then assign them to the other entries in the database. Is this a feasible plan? How would I go about this?

Here are some examples of what entries in this database look like:

```
2015-09-01 00:00:00,Buffalo,"42.9405299,-78.8697906",10.1016/s0894-7317(12)00840-1,42.9405299,-78.8697906,43.0,-79.0
2015-09-01 00:00:00,New York,"40.7830603,-73.9712488",10.1016/j.jmv.2014.04.008,40.783060299999995,-73.9712488,41.0,-74.0
2015-09-01 00:00:04,Scottsdale,"33.4941704,-111.9260519",10.1016/j.euroneuro.2014.05.008,33.494170399999994,-111.9260519,33.0,-112.0
2015-09-01 00:00:09,Provo,"40.2338438,-111.6585337",10.1016/j.toxac.2014.07.002,40.233843799999995,-111.6585337,40.0,-112.0
2015-09-01 00:00:13,New York,"40.7830603,-73.9712488",10.1016/j.drugalcdep.2014.09.015,40.783060299999995,-73.9712488,41.0,-74.0
2015-09-01 00:00:16,Fremont,"37.5482697,-121.9885719",10.1016/j.ajic.2012.04.160,37.548269700000006,-121.98857190000001,38.0,-122.0
2015-09-01 00:00:24,Provo,"40.2338438,-111.6585337",10.1016/j.chroma.2015.01.036,40.233843799999995,-111.6585337,40.0,-112.0
```

I am using the [geocoder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder) package for geolocation. Here is some code I've written that could handle that:

```
def convert_to_state(lati, long):
    lat, lon = float(lati), float(long)
    g = geocoder.google([lat, lon], method='reverse')
    state_long, state_short = g.state_long, g.state
    return state_long, state_short
```

I'm just not sure how to do this. Turns out geocoding is pretty expensive, so using the duplicates is probably the best way forward. Any suggestions for how to accomplish that?

Comment: You might be able to use an SQL query to get unique data, coordinates for instance. Try something like `SELECT DISTINCT city, coordinates FROM table`. You are going to have to substitute in the correct column and table names though.

Comment: I've never used SQL and don't really have enough time to learn. Is there any way that this can be accomplished in python and pandas?

Comment: you could create a nested list using a for loop after getting the data and just check if the new data is a duplicate

Comment: @Merlin My mistake, I forgot to include the column names. The last 2 columns are rounded coordinates for use in groupby.

Comment: run this  to see number of uniques       df.groupby(['City','lat',"long"]).count().count()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the hash table idea, but here is an alternative using some pandas stuff:

1) get a unique list of (lat, lon) coords

```
df['latlon'] = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['lati'].tolist(),df['long'].tolist())]
unique_ll = df['latlon'].unique()
```

2) loop through unique coords and set the state for all equivalent lines

```
for l in unique_ll:
    df.loc[df['latlon'] == l, 'state'] = convert_to_state(l[0],l[1])
```

Comment: You should mention: `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_csv(filename);`

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly the best way to avoid doing extra work will be to use a hash table to check if something already had a mapping:

```
processed_coords = {}
def convert_to_state(lati, long):
    lat, lon = float(lati), float(long)
    if (lat, lon) not in processed_coords:
        g = geocoder.google([lat, lon], method='reverse')
        state_long, state_short = g.state_long, g.state
        processed_coords[(lat,lon)] = (state_long, state_short)
        return state_long, state_short
    else:
        return processed_coords[(lat,lon)]
```

This way you do a simple O(1) check to see if you already have the data, which isn't much extra calculation at all, and you don't redo the work if you indeed have already done it.

If you're right and there's only 6500 sets of unique coordinates, you should be fine in terms of memory usage for this technique, but if you're wrong and there are more unique ones, you may run into some memory issues if more of those million something are unique.

Answer (score 1):

There's a geo-info service SmartyStreets that has a list tool that processes lists of searches and returns a bunch of information (can upload a spreadsheet or copy and paste). They focus on address validation so they expect search terms to be addresses, however, it can match just zip codes to cities and states. Do you have access to that info?

Here's a [link to the demo](https://smartystreets.com/demo/list).